# Spring Boot AMQP class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class com.example.model.X

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, generics, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have 2 services with request/response pattern on **Kotlin** Spring Boot.
In producer I tried to use generic for send method to don't write several methods with different return types:

```
fun <T> sendMessage(data: String) : T {
    val listenableFuture = asyncRabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceiveAsType(
        directExchange.name,
        "routing-key",
        data,
        object : ParameterizedTypeReference<T>() {}
    )
    return listenableFuture.get()
}
```

And for instance I use this method with one of Model classes:
**Producer:**

```
fun getData(): ExampleDto {
    ...
    return rabbitTemplate.sendMessage<ExampleDto>("data")
}
```

**Consumer:**

```
...
@RabbitListener(...)
fun consumer(data: String): ExampleDto {
    ...
    // processing with data
    return ExampleDto(...)
}
```

So I get exception `class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class com.example.model.ExampleDto (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.example.model.ExampleDto is in unnamed module of loader 'app')`
If I write method without generics and declare return type directly, then everything works well. But I don't want to write dozens of methods that are different only in return type.

Comment: not sure what you are doing here. method `getData` expects `ExampleDto`, but sending `String` to rabbitmq with type `ExampleDto`? What are you trying to achieve here? are you sending or receiving data?

Comment: I added example to my question. `getData` takes `String` and returns `ExampleDto`. Method produces message to another server with consumer and wait response with `ExampleDto`. No matter what type of object I produce. Consumer gets  data from queue, processes it and return `ExampleDto` object back to server. I can't receive `ExampleDto` if I use generics for send method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `ParameterizedTypeReference` is used to implement [Super Type Token](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) pattern. When you pass `T` as a parameter type, the underlying logic in `convertSendAndReceiveAsType` cannot infer the exact type due to generic [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

You either need to parametrize your `sendMessage` method with `ParameterizedTypeReference` and create it with concrete type in `getData()` or you can use [Reified type parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) Kotlin feature to overcome this with synthetic sugar. E.g.

```
inline fun <reified T> sendMessage(data: String) : T {
    val listenableFuture = asyncRabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceiveAsType(
        directExchange.name,
        "routing-key",
        data,
        object : ParameterizedTypeReference<T>() {}
    )
    return listenableFuture.get()
}
```

Comment: It works! But I had to write that inline function in abstract class and implement in @Component rabbit producer class because of `'inline' modifier is not allowed on virtual members. Only private or final members can be inlined`. So it's not a big problem.